# validating html files with latex commands

Tags: html, latex

I'm using latex commands in my html code. When I validate the at w3c validator, it is giving me inavlid markup message.

```
Line 105, Column 31: non SGML character number 12

    \begin{equation}(x^{2})^{4+(frac{1}{5})}\end{equation}
```

Is there a way to pass validation? Can I ignore this error?

Comment: I don't think the line given is the problem. Is there an ampersand (`&`) on a previous line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`non SGML character number 12` means that you have a control character in your html source. This is likely to be a mistake. Try to spot this character and delete it. Alternatively, retype the line that is causing you the problem.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. The actual code was, \begin{equation}(x^{2})^{4+(\frac{1}{5})}\end{equation} and when it was validated, it became \begin{equation}(x^{2})^{4+(rac{1}{5})}\end{equation}, so i added double backslash before f. and it validated my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put your LaTex code into a CDATA block:

```
<![CDATA[
\begin{equation}(x^{2})^{4+(frac{1}{5})}\end{equation}
]]>
```